# Elasticsearch 5 stops during long indexing

Tags: java, elasticsearch, garbage-collection, elasticsearch-5

I'm indexing **2B small documents** on a single node with **ES 5.4**.

Documents are organized in **~3K indexes**, for a total of **2TB**. The indexes' occupancy varies from few KB to hundreds of GB and they are sharded in order to keep each **shard under 5GB**.

I'm indexing with 14 threads concurrently on different indexes with **bulk** requests of **2K documents each**. The server has **16CPU and 32GB of RAM** and no reads are performed during this indexing process.

Relevant ES configurations are:

- `Xms12g -Xmx12g` in `jvm.options`
- `bootstrap.memory_lock:true`
- `indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 95%`
- `MAX_OPEN_FILES=1000000`

After 50~100M indexed documents ES starts to slow down drastically.

In the logs I read:

```
[2017-05-11T16:44:24,751][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][2141] overhead, spent [13.5s] collecting in the last [14.3s]
[2017-05-11T16:44:40,323][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][old][2143][337] duration [14s], collections [1]/[14.5s], total [14s]/[54.2m], memory [11.8gb]->[11.4gb]/[11.8gb], all_pools {[young] [865.3mb]->[533.8mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [75mb]->[0b]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [10.9gb]->[10.9gb]/[10.9gb]}
[2017-05-11T16:44:40,323][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][2143] overhead, spent [14s] collecting in the last [14.5s]
[2017-05-11T16:44:53,004][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][old][2145][338] duration [10.8s], collections [1]/[11.6s], total [10.8s]/[54.4m], memory [11.8gb]->[11.4gb]/[11.8gb], all_pools {[young] [865.3mb]->[538.9mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [44.9mb]->[0b]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [10.9gb]->[10.9gb]/[10.9gb]}
[2017-05-11T16:44:53,004][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][2145] overhead, spent [10.8s] collecting in the last [11.6s]
[2017-05-11T16:45:05,141][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][old][2147][339] duration [11s], collections [1]/[11.1s], total [11s]/[54.6m], memory [11.8gb]->[11.4gb]/[11.8gb], all_pools {[young] [865.3mb]->[558.3mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [103.1mb]->[0b]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [10.9gb]->[10.9gb]/[10.9gb]}
[2017-05-11T16:45:05,142][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][2147] overhead, spent [11s] collecting in the last [11.1s]
[2017-05-11T16:45:19,928][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][old][2149][340] duration [13s], collections [1]/[13.7s], total [13s]/[54.8m], memory [11.8gb]->[11.5gb]/[11.8gb], all_pools {[young] [865.3mb]->[570.1mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [48.9mb]->[0b]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [10.9gb]->[10.9gb]/[10.9gb]}
[2017-05-11T16:45:19,928][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][2149] overhead, spent [13s] collecting in the last [13.7s]
[2017-05-11T16:45:35,926][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][old][2152][341] duration [13.7s], collections [1]/[13.8s], total [13.7s]/[55.1m], memory [11.8gb]->[11.5gb]/[11.8gb], all_pools {[young] [865.3mb]->[575mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [104.6mb]->[0b]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [10.9gb]->[10.9gb]/[10.9gb]}
[2017-05-11T16:45:35,931][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][2152] overhead, spent [13.7s] collecting in the last [13.8s]
[2017-05-11T16:45:49,919][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][old][2154][342] duration [12.8s], collections [1]/[12.9s], total [12.8s]/[55.3m], memory [11.8gb]->[11.5gb]/[11.8gb], all_pools {[young] [865.3mb]->[577.1mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [102.3mb]->[0b]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [10.9gb]->[10.9gb]/[10.9gb]}
[2017-05-11T16:45:49,919][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][2154] overhead, spent [12.8s] collecting in the last [12.9s]
[2017-05-11T16:46:03,976][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][old][2156][343] duration [12.1s], collections [1]/[13s], total [12.1s]/[55.5m], memory [11.8gb]->[11.5gb]/[11.8gb], all_pools {[young] [865.3mb]->[601mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [50.9mb]->[0b]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [10.9gb]->[10.9gb]/[10.9gb]}
[2017-05-11T16:46:03,976][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [VT0Xr1c] [gc][2156] overhead, spent [12.1s] collecting in the last [13s]
```

Looking at the end dates of the GC, they all are quite the same of the start dates of the next GC. These GCs have a duration of more than 10seconds and it seems that they are blocking ES to prevent Java from going out of memory.
As soon as ES halts for GC, the bulk requests go in timeout (30 seconds or more) and the indexing process fails.

With ES 2.4 I hadn't this problem. I'm using ES 5.4 because I read that now it splits better the heap among the indexes.

Am I doing anything wrong?
What should I change in order to keep the performance high during the entire indexing process?

Comment: And you used the same exact configuration and indexing approach and hardware resources in 2.4 and it worked? I doubt it.

Comment: In ES 2.4 the indexer threads were only 3 and the index_buffer_size was 90% (and not 95%).

Comment: In this case the relevant bit was the low amount of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there are too many indices, and shards can be bigger: 30-50GB or even more.

And if 95% of the heap is used for indexing processes (`indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 95%`) how do you expect ES to store the terms, inverted index and all other data structures? In which memory? You need to give it some room. For a 2TB data size, I wouldn't go higher than `index_buffer_size: 50%`.

Comment: So I tried 2 configurations:
- 3 indexer threads and 95% of index_buffer_size. It takes 42h to index everything.
- 14 indexer threads and 50% of index_buffer_size. It takes 30h to index everything.

In both the cases: no error found!

PS: since those data structures are shared both for indexing and searching phase, I supposed that the 95% for the index_buffer_size was computed after deducting their memory required.

Comment: `indices.memory.index_buffer_size
Accepts either a percentage or a byte size value. It defaults to 10%, meaning that 10% of the total heap allocated to a node will be used as the indexing buffer size shared across all shards.` from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/indexing-buffer.html